# Find predicted classification on validation data set

Tags: python, tensorflow, machine-learning, neural-network

I am working on a neural network using TensorFlow that takes in feature vectors of length 1476 and is attempting to classify each feature vector into one of 6 categories (labels).  The NN itself does not have a problem, but have been unsuccessful in finding how to get the predicted label's on the validation data set.  For reference, here is my neural network:

```
#define the model
model = Sequential()
model.add(Dense(units=100,activation='tanh', input_dim=1476))
model.add(Dropout(0.5))
model.add(Dense(units=100,activation='tanh'))
model.add(Dropout(0.5))
model.add(Dense(units=6,activation='tanh'))
```

And then here is the model being fitted with the validation data set included (Note that I recognize `fit_transform` should be converted to `fit` method):

```
model.fit_generator(generator(2000),
                    epochs=3000,
                    steps_per_epoch=1,
                    validation_data=validationGenerator(),
                    validation_steps=40,
                    verbose=2,
                    callbacks=[tensorboard,checkpoint,csv_logger])
```

The `generator` and `validationGenerator` methods are just getting the training/validation data and label's to be fed in.  When the model is ran, I am able to see the standard output per epoch, containing the training accuracy and loss, along with the validation accuracy and loss.

My question is if there is a way to see more info into the validation accuracy.  I want to be able to see the predicted outputs vs the ground truth's for each feature vector in the validation data set per epoch.  Is this at all possible? I want to be able to see if my model is classifying heavily towards only a few specific labels.

Comment: You can save the weights during each epoch with checkpoints then just load back those saved weights. You could compute predictions by implementing a callback function. if you search something like that on stackoverflow, you'll find some results I'm sure.

Comment: @rocket_boomerang_19 Thank you for presenting this option, but is there no other way to split it out? You are saying just save the training weights at that epoch and just run validation through a callback? I would have to manually iterate over each validation point correct?

Comment: I would pass your label encoder and validation set to a callback, run predictions through the model on epoch end, inverse_transform the predictions back to labels, and then use sci-kit learns classification report to get an impression of how the model is doing on a per-label basis